# How to narrow down scope when working with derived types in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

Given the following derived type definitions:

```
export enum Streams {
    NormalStream = 'normal',
    PatternStream = 'pattern',
}

export interface VesselStreamDefinition<Data, IsPatternStream extends boolean = boolean> {
    data?: Data;
    streamType: Streams;
    patternStream: IsPatternStream;
    parser: (data: any) => Data;
}
const stream = <Data, IsPatternStream extends boolean>(stream: VesselStreamDefinition<Data, IsPatternStream>) => stream;

export type VesselStreamDefinitions = typeof vesselStreams;
export type StreamVesselData = {
    [T in Streams]?: VesselStreamDefinitions[T]['patternStream'] extends false
        ? VesselStreamDefinitions[T]['data']
        : { [key: string]: NonNullable<VesselStreamDefinitions[T]['data']> };
};

export const vesselStreams = {
    [Streams.PatternStream]: stream<number, true>({
        streamType: Streams.PatternStream,
        patternStream: true,
        parser: (data) => data,
    }),
    [Streams.NormalStream]: stream<string, false>({
        streamType: Streams.NormalStream,
        patternStream: false,
        parser: (data) => data,
    }),
};
```

This code allows me to have a derived data type of two types of streams, normal and pattern stream. Datatype of a normal stream is just a value while the pattern stream gets a dictionary of its values, this way I can read the pattern stream from many diffferent sources and handle parsing correctly.

The problem though is that I cannot figure out how to handle this data properly with types in cases like this:

```
const result: StreamVesselData = {};
function fillStreamData<T extends Streams>(
    streamType: T,
    definition: (typeof vesselStreams)[T],
    data: any,
    streamName: string,
) {
    if (!definition) return;
    if (definition.patternStream == true) {
        const parsedData = definition.parser(data); // would use parser here
        if (!parsedData) return;
        const newData = { id: parsedData };
        result[streamType] = newData;
    } else {
        const parsedData = definition.parser(data); // would use parser here
        if (!parsedData) return;
        result[streamType] = parsedData;
    }
}
```

I cannot assign the data to a result without first casting is as any or something. Is there a way to narrow down the scope so that after checking the patternStream field value, typescript would figure out what the data type is.

This is a simple example but I get more complicated ones too where I end up casting to any.

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling that you need a classic discriminated union here but that you made it more complex than needed.

First, there is no need for enums in TypeScript - they are supported but they don't bring anything over type aliases except complexity:

```js
export type StreamType = 'normal' | 'pattern';
```

Then I would create a union type from both possible variants of VesselStreamDefinition:

```js
interface BaseVesselStreamDefinition<Type extends StreamType, Data> {
    data?: Data;
    streamType: Type;
    parser: (data: any) => Data;
}

export type VesselStreamDefinition =
    | BaseVesselStreamDefinition<"pattern", { id: string; }>
    | BaseVesselStreamDefinition<"normal", string>
    ;
```

Last, I would create the `VesselStreams` type itself, associating each of its keys to the correct `VesselStreamDefinition` member:

```
type VesselStreams = {
    [Property in StreamType]: VesselStreamDefinition & { streamType: Property; }
};

export const vesselStreams: VesselStreams = {
    pattern: ({ // only pattern and normal are allowed to index the record, compiler would complain if any other key is used
        streamType: "pattern", // passing anything but "pattern" would make the compiler complain
        parser: (data) => {
            return {
                id: data
            }; // returning anything but a {id: string} would make the compiler complain
        },
    }),
    normal: ({
        streamType: "normal", // passing anything but "normal" would make the compiler complain
        parser: (data) => {
            return String(data); // returning anything but a string would make the compiler complain
        },
    }),
};
```

The secret lies in this type:

```
VesselStreamDefinition & { streamType: Property; }
```

It narrows the `VesselStreamDefinition` union to only the members that extends `{ streamType: Property; }`. This is an all-time classic of the type theory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However this eliminates the main point of doing what I'm doing which is to be able to handle simple data streams where the parser takes everything and returns a value, and pattern streams where parser returns only a part of the value. I guess I could use this and then use spread operator to combine the pattern streams but that is very inneficient for a large amount of streams. The idea is to use redis keys like this: `foo:*:bar` and do a redis scan or geosearch to find all the right keys and read and parse each stream separately collecting all the data in one dict